# Pandas how to group and sort by a column and convert it to a Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Hi I am new to Pandas and I am trying to figure out how do I group by a specific column and then sort by a column and convert the group object to panda data frame.

For example:

```
ID   DATE         NAME
a1   2017-11-02   Mark 
b1   2017-11-03   Nick
c1   2017-11-04   Paul
a1   2017-11-01   Seth
c1   2017-11-05   Tom
b1   2017-11-02   Jerry
a1   2017-11-04   Happy
```

and the output I am looking for is

```
ID   DATE        NAME
a1   2017-11-01  Seth
a1   2017-11-02  Mark
a1   2017-11-04  Happy
b1   2017-11-02  Jerry
b1   2017-11-03  Nick
c1   2017-11-04  Paul
c1   2017-11-05  Tom
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is dupe, need `df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'DATE'])`

Comment: thanks ...it worked